# Не работает программа

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем здравствуйте. Писал программу по знакам зодиака, но она почему-то не работает. Честно скажу, в python опыта мало. Буду благодарен за ответ.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *

def check():
    x = znak.get()
    if x=="Овен":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "21 мар. - 20 апр.")
    elif x=="Телец":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "21 апр. - 21 мая.")
    elif x=="Близнецы":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "22 мая - 21 июн.")
    elif x=="Рак":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "22 июн. - 22 июл.")
    elif x=="Лев":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "23 июля - 21 авг.")
    elif x=="Дева":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "22 авг. - 23 сен.")
    elif x=="Весы":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "24 сен. - 23 окт.")
    elif x=="Скорпион":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "24 окт. - 22 ноя.")
    elif x=="Стрелец":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "23 ноя. - 22 дек.")
    elif x=="Козерог":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "23 дек. - 20 янв.")
    elif x=="Водолей":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "21 янв. - 19 фев.")
    elif x=="Рыбы":
        rez.delete(0, END)
        rez.insert(0, "20 фев. - 20 мар.")

window = Tk()
window.geometry("400x350")
window.title("Знаки зодиака")

text = Label(window, text="Ваш знак зодиака")
text.place(x=150, y=30)

znak = Entry(window)
znak.place(x=150, y=50)

btn = Button(window, text="Получить информацию", command="check")
btn.place(x=150, y=80)

text2 = Label(window, text="Ваш знак зодиака")
text2.place(x=150, y=110)

rez = Entry(window)
rez.place(x=150, y=140)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Расскажите подробнее. Происходит какая-то ошибка?

Comment: нет. Просто в строку не выводится текст (который используется в def). Всё выполняется без ошибок.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кавычки у команды не нужны. Без кавычек у меня заработало:

```
btn = Button(window, text="Получить информацию", command=check)
```